Can a FIDO2 Security Token be removed after unlocking a LUKS volume at boot?
A FIDO2 security token should be used for decrypting all disks in a linux machine at boot. systemd allows this since version 248.
Can the FIDO2 Security Token be removed after boot when using LUKS for full disk encryption, or does it need to remain plugged in for the disk to be usable for read/write operations?

Accessing an external FIDO2 token on every disk operation would make an encrypted disk device very slow, to the point of being practically unusable.
With LUKS, any password, FIDO2 token or other means of unlocking the encryption is used to decrypt an encrypted master key from one of the keyslots in the LUKS header. This master key is then used with a symmetric cipher that is suited for block-oriented use; this cipher is then used for encrypting/decrypting any blocks outside the LUKS header on the encrypted device.
Once the device is unlocked, the decrypted master key must be kept in RAM to access the encrypted device. As a result, unplugging the security token won't remove kernel's access to the master key of the LUKS device. So the answer is, yes, the token can be removed.
Of course, it would be possible to implement a watchdog program that will perform the necessary steps to stop accessing the encrypted device and destroy the in-memory key on token removal. But that would be separate from systemd-cryptsetup. Such a watchdog program would have to be prepared to kill -9 any processes that would be in the way of closing the encrypted device, if necessary: otherwise it won't be able to guarantee closing the device quickly.

This is what I expected. Thanks for your comprehensive answer!

If the in-memory master key is removed, will the encrypted partition be no longer be available?

Normally,  cryptsetup close is what causes the master key to be removed from memory along with all the other things that need to happen when stopping access to the encrypted partition in a controlled manner.. If you somehow overwrite the in-memory master key, the system might write some blocks to the encrypted disk using an incorrect master key, effectively corrupting the filesystem inside the encrypted partition.
